# Can I read a JSON property with varying names into a specific property on my class with JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an annoying conundrum where I have multiple types being returned from an API and the only difference between them is the property names. One type will have an int of `Count` the other will have an int of `Customers` and another will have an int of `Replies`.

Classes Example:

```
public class DateAndCount
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class DateAndCount
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int Customers { get; set; }
}

public class DateAndCount
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int Replies { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Example:

```
{
  "count": 40,
  "date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},

{
  "customers": 40,
  "date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},

{
  "replies": 40,
  "date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},
```

Instead of having to create 3+ nearly identical classes, can I somehow just have the serializer deserialize any property name into the `Count` property?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is kind of code-smelly: you could use `JsonExtensionData`, which would mean collating the `customers`, `count`, and `date` json property/values into a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Not sure if you want to do it that way.

Comment: I agree, that is a bit smelly. There was another comment here that recommend the best I can do is have a class with the data and just inherit from that for the int. I wen't ahead and did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple `JsonConverter` to handle this:

```
class DateAndCountConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(DateAndCount));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        DateAndCount dac = new DateAndCount();
        dac.Date = (DateTime?)jo["Date"];
        // put the value of the first integer property from the JSON into Count
        dac.Count = (int)jo.Properties().First(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Integer).Value;
        return dac;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, decorate your `DateAndCount` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to tie the converter to your class, and deserialize as usual.  Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParseAndDump(@"{ ""Date"" : ""2015-08-22T19:02:42Z"", ""Count"" : 40 }");
        ParseAndDump(@"{ ""Date"" : ""2015-08-20T15:55:04Z"", ""Customers"" : 26 }");
        ParseAndDump(@"{ ""Date"" : ""2015-08-21T10:17:31Z"", ""Replies"" : 35 }");
    }

    private static void ParseAndDump(string json)
    {
        DateAndCount dac = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateAndCount>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Date: " + dac.Date);
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + dac.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(DateAndCountConverter))]
class DateAndCount
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 8/22/2015 7:02:42 PM
Count: 40

Date: 8/20/2015 3:55:04 PM
Count: 26

Date: 8/21/2015 10:17:31 AM
Count: 35
```